# OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) not working. N.B: Only when calling with parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I just started learning unity for a gaming project. As I'm following different tutorials it came to collision between objects.

So, when I used the OnCollisionEnter without anything written inside the parenthesis it works; the code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter()
{
  Debug.Log("Collision Happens");
}
```

So, if this code above works it means I have all the rigid body and collier added to all three game objects presents and the OnCollisionEnter is calling ok.

But now when I'm trying to get specific information like which object it is colliding with, I cannot get it done. Here are some ways I tried to do that. At first I wrote:

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
       Debug.Log(collisionInfo.collider.name);
    }
```

But may be because this code was taken from a tutorial 2017, unity API Updated automatically updates my code to this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
       Debug.Log(collisionInfo.GetComponent<Collider>().name);
    }
```

But yet, nothing on the console output except an warning/error:

**Script error: OnCollisionEnter
This message parameter has to be of type: Collision
The message will be ignored.**

Then I tried another way:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
       Debug.Log(col.gameObject.name);
    }
```

Actually my final aim is to add an if else condition where it will check

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "ball")
{ \\then do something }
```

But in order to do that I wanted to get the name of the object its colliding with in console output.

As a new learner, I might be doing something wrong or can it be an installation issue?? Please advice/suggest what to do.

Edit: Now a new error starts to pop out whenever I open a script in Visual Studio from Unity.

Error message: ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.CompilationUnit.LanguageOf (SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.CompilationUnit unit) (at <5d31b1d9508e46c08a62d03725bffebc>:0)
SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.CompilationUnit.CompilationUnits () (at <5d31b1d9508e46c08a62d03725bffebc>:0)
SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.ProjectSystem.UnitySolutionBuilder..ctor () (at <5d31b1d9508e46c08a62d03725bffebc>:0)
SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.ProjectSystem.UnitySolutionBuilder.CreateSolutionFromAssetDatabase () (at <5d31b1d9508e46c08a62d03725bffebc>:0)
SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.ProjectFilesGenerator.GenerateProject () (at <5d31b1d9508e46c08a62d03725bffebc>:0)
SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.ProjectFilePostprocessor.OnPreGeneratingCSProjectFiles () (at <5d31b1d9508e46c08a62d03725bffebc>:0)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at :0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at :0)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at :0)
UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal.InvokeMethod (System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Object[] args) (at :0)
UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal.OnPreGeneratingCSProjectFiles () (at :0)
UnityEditor.VisualStudioIntegration.SolutionSynchronizer.Sync () (at :0)
UnityEditor.SyncVS.SyncIfFirstFileOpenSinceDomainLoad () (at :0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

> Blockquote

Comment: Is the colliders 2d?

Comment: No. Just rechecked, non of the colliders are 2d.

Comment: Is some of objects move too fast? Like a bullet

Comment: No. Everything is pretty normal. Btw, I just faced another error and I'm afraid it might be a compatibility issue. I'm still using Visual Studio 2012, do you think it can be a issue?

Comment: No.
I just want to confirm; Is any of the colliders you want to debug its name is a trigger?(To check if it's trigger go to Collider Component  > Is Trigger)

Comment: And is the GameObject that include your collision script is a trigger?

Comment: No, all the "Is Trigger" are unchecked. Including the object with the script. Btw, at first the first code was giving output but now even that is not working anymore. Whenever I open the script in Visual Studio this error occurs:

"ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.CompilationUnit.LanguageOf (SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.CompilationUnit unit) (at <5d31b1d9508e46c08a62d03725bffebc>:0)
SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.CompilationUnit.CompilationUnits () (at <5d31b1d9508e46c08a62d03725bff....."

Comment: Idk, I just create a new project with your collision method and it works fine

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I'm gonna reinstall both Visual Studio and Unity. Results are not constant, giving wired output for same codes.

Comment: The parameter is required for Unity recognizing the message method! Signatures for these "magic" methods have to match exactly the signature shown in the API

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Uninstalled VS 2012 & then installed VS 2017. Now everything's working so far.